# Unable to Load Helper in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, linux, codeigniter, web

I am moving an application from a Windows server to a Linux server. It works well on the Windows server, but on the Linux server I get this message:

```
unable to load requested file:
helpers/fusioncharts_helper.php
```

I understand that Linux servers are case-sensitive, and I factored that in. What else could it be?

Comment: Does the file exist in the right place? Is it readable by the user running the web server (often `apache`)?

Comment: ... Please include `ls -l` output when answering Francis's questions...

Comment: I don't mean to hijack the question, but seeing as there's no answers yet and it's still fairly new (<1 month old)...

@FrancisAvila - What permissions should I be seeing? I have this error too on a linux shared hosting environment. I can't seem to get a helper of mine loaded via autoload. I just set my `application/helpers/` folder to `chmod 755` recursively, but no luck. :/

Comment: I wasn't able to solve this. Zack if you managed this let me know. There was no any output in my case since the helper could not be loaded. The page remained blank according to my settings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try creating a new file on the linux system and cutting and pasting the code from the old file into the new?  Permissions errors in a linux environment can be frustrating to new-ish linux users and rather than trying to chmod your way out, sometimes its just easier to make a new file and copy the code over?  I had a permissions error once where I was logged in as super user admin on my laptop, made some files and did some coding, then when I zipped the project, emailed it to myself and loaded it on my desktop, I could view/edit the code, but when I attempted to execute it on my desktop I was getting weird errors even when logged in as super user.  Turned out to be a permissions problem related to two different systems, and even though I was logged in as super user, the system wasn't allowing access to those files since they were generated on an outside system...  The solution was to just cut and paste the code out into a fresh file.